# Update ORACLE table and return IDs (PK) of updated rows to PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to use UPDATE query towards Oracle(12g) database and use "RETURNING col INTO :var" or "RETURNING col BULK COLLECT INTO :var" clasule and use it to get list of all IDs (PK column) which were updated, into PHP variable.
I was able to get one, the last, but not a list.

I've already played and researched with using oci_bind_array_by_name but received error "Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01484: arrays can only be bound to PL/SQL statements" and received array in PHP was empty.

Example (stripped of error handling) which throws above error:

```
$db = oci_connect($db_user,$db_password,$db_connection_string);
$bids = '1,2';
$sql = "UPDATE sch.table_name
        SET processing_status = '050',
                printed_by= :username,
                printed_date=current_date,
                change_date = sysdate,
                change_by = :username
            WHERE batch_id in (" . $bids . ")
            RETURNING batch_id  BULK COLLECT INTO :updated_batch_ids";
$stid = oci_parse($db, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stid,':username', $username, -1, SQLT_CHR);
oci_bind_array_by_name($stid,':updated_batch_ids',$updated_batches,1000,50);

oci_execute($stid,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
oci_free_statement($stid);

//expecting data in $updated_batches, but its empty
```

I've also try to use oci_fetch_array or oci_fetch_all (statement), but that resulted in error: "oci_fetch_all(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch".

Help is greatly appreciated.
One last note out of my frustration: This would be much easier/available/documented/solved with Postgre, but have to use Oracle.

Research and tries/tests oci_fetch..., oci_bind_array_by_name, oci_new_collection did not gain desirable results.

I would like DB to return into PHP variable list or array of IDs (PK - batch_ids) which were really updated by query.

Comment: Did you initialise `$updated_batches = [];` before the call to use it?

Comment: I did with and without initiating and it did not make any difference.

Comment: This form discussion may help you: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/pl-sql-collection-table-into-php-array-1043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some more digging I came up with this. It returns one column, indexed (not associative) array into PHP, but does the job. I will grant upvote to anybody who will figure out how to get more than one column, different types (e.g. number and varchar) into associative array in PHP.

Solution is to

1. modify query to create table type of correct type
2. create variable of that table type and feed data into that variable
3. Ultimately provide that data to binded variable in PHP.

One more problem is OCI's requirement to set size of binded array (1000 in below code) - works for me but may not for all applications.

In below code I construct query by concatenation, as in my environment (source of $bids) is secure and SQL inception checked before. Also the code is stripped of error handling.

Query construction:

```
$sql = "DECLARE
    --declare table type
    TYPE batch_id_array IS TABLE OF myschema.mytable.batch_id%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    l_batch_ids batch_id_array; --variable used to RETURN into
BEGIN 
    UPDATE myschema.mytabe
        SET processing_status = '050',
            printed_by= :username,
            printed_date=current_date,
            WHERE batch_id in " . $bids  . "
        RETURNING
            batch_id
        BULK COLLECT INTO l_batch_ids;
    :batch_ids := l_batch_ids; --set binded variable
END;";
```

Connect, Parse, Bind, Execute and Free:

```
$stid = oci_parse($db, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stid,':username', $username, -1, SQLT_CHR);
#bind array - output variable
oci_bind_array_by_name($stid, ':batch_ids', $batch_ids, 1000,-1, SQLT_INT);
#execute and free statement
oci_execute($stid,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
oci_free_statement($stid);

# $batch_bids is now indexed array of integers with updated batch_ids
var_dump($batch_bids);
```